# IOS How to alter an existing UI to use a new navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Ok, I'm having trouble with this.

I started an Application with a UITableViewController custom class called MainView.

In interface builder I modified the view so that there is a text box and a button on top and a UITableView. Connected the data source and delegate to the MainView class, and programmed in all the code to use the text field as a search field, the button as a search trigger, and then programmed in the proper delegate methods to populate the UITableView. This works perfectly.

Now the next step was to use the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method to be able to show a webview with a link related to the selected row. So reading I see that I need to add a UINavigationController to the mix ( so as to get the toolbar and navigation bar etc..).

Now I tried this:
add a navigation controller from the Interface builder, and connect to the appdelegate, and an outlet

```
#import 

@interface ComparateurAppDelegate : NSObject  {
    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

then in the implementation

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

this launches ok, same as before, and I don't have the top bar I should have. plus when I try to push a new view in it does nothing.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController.nib" bundle:nil];
```

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:wvc animated:YES];

[wvc release];
}
```

I know the code is running because I nslog it. but nothing is happening. WebViewController.nib is the nib file I created ( empty right now) so that I populate it with a UIwebview.

My guess at this moment is that the view hierarchy is not set ok.

So I tried a few things I can't remember exactly and got the toolbar on top of the window I already have, but with all the content inaccessible ( like if the toolbar was a modal dialog and I could not use the bottom one , or like a transparent view and you could see underneath to the first window that was stacked).
I also tried creating programatically the UINavigation controller in the appDelegate like so

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *rootController = [[MainView alloc]init];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootController];
    [rootController release];
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

And all I got is an empty UITableView for an interface, and not the MainView.nib ( whose class is set as MainView).

TL;DR:
Have an app that is working, want to add detailed view, and need to modify to a UINavigationController but can't seem to find the proper way to do it.

thanks in advance and sorry for the long post.

Comment: A long post with details beats a short post without details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
UIViewController *rootController = [[MainView alloc]init];
```

To this:

```
UIViewController *rootController = [[MainView alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried and now I get this error.<pre><code>2011-01-07 14:20:42.875 Comparateur[46985:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MainView 0x6a376c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key delegate.'
</code></pre>

Comment: this and I had to move the view in IB in order to put the view in the controller.